Subscribe to Real-Time data ~ MT5 Python
I've been able to easily fetch historical data from MetaTrader 5 (MT5) using the MT5 Python API. However, I'm struggling to find a way to receive real-time market updates similar to subscribing to a WebSocket.
I need a solution that allows me to subscribe to real-time data updates for a specific symbol (e.g., XAUUSD) and get notified of new tick or OHLC data as soon as it becomes available. Does the MT5 API support this functionality, or is there an alternative approach to achieve real-time data streaming in MT5?
